# How to check whether my coordinates lies in map visible region?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, mkmapview

I am able to get NE and SW coordintes of visible region in my mapview.

But find difficulties in how can I check whether my coordinates lies between these NE and SW coordinates.

E.g. Suppose my SW coordinates are "38.94271",
    "-94.68807" and my NE coordinates are  "39.06544300754172",
    "-94.57821056524351".

Now my location's latitude is 22.354643 and longitude is 10.34532 then How can I check whether my location lies or not in the specific region?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
+ (BOOL)coordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord inRegion:(MKCoordinateRegion)region
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center = region.center;
    MKCoordinateSpan span = region.span;

    BOOL result = YES;
    result &= cos((center.latitude - coord.latitude)*M_PI/180.0) > cos(span.latitudeDelta/2.0*M_PI/180.0);
    result &= cos((center.longitude - coord.longitude)*M_PI/180.0) > cos(span.longitudeDelta/2.0*M_PI/180.0);
    return result;
}
```

This should do the trick. Adapt it for your needs.